# What's the relation between the conditional expectation of the score of the likelihood, and score of the conditional likelihood?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, likelihood, conditional-expectation

We wish to estimate the parameter $\boldsymbol\theta$ from data $\bf X$ in the presence of nuisance parameter $\boldsymbol\Phi$.

Suppose $\bf T$ is a complete and sufficient statistic for $\boldsymbol\Phi$ for fixed $\boldsymbol\theta$, such that the likelihood can factorize

$$f_X({\bf X}; \boldsymbol\theta,\boldsymbol\Phi) = f_{X | T}({\bf X} | {\bf T} ; \boldsymbol\theta) f_T({\bf T}; \boldsymbol\theta,\boldsymbol\Phi)$$

I've read that

$$ \frac{\partial \log(f_X({\bf X}; \boldsymbol\theta,\boldsymbol\Phi))}{\partial \boldsymbol\theta} - E_\boldsymbol\theta\left[\frac{\partial \log(f_X({\bf X}; \boldsymbol\theta,\boldsymbol\Phi))}{\partial \boldsymbol\theta} \mid {\bf T} \right] = \frac{\partial \log(f_{X | T}({\bf X} | {\bf T}; \boldsymbol\theta))}{\partial \boldsymbol\theta}$$

For example, see [Liang and Zeger (1995)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1177010028) (equation 3.3) and [Lindsay (1982)](https://academic.oup.com/biomet/article-abstract/69/3/503/220843) (equation 2.1).

In other words, the residual of the derivative with respect to $\boldsymbol\theta$ of the loglikelihood of the data under its best prediction by a function of ${\bf T}$, is equal to the derivative of with respect to $\boldsymbol\theta$ of the conditional loglikelihood of the data given ${\bf T}$.

How do I prove that this is true?

As a start, I note that we can write

$$ \frac{\partial \log(f_{X | T}({\bf X} | {\bf T}; \boldsymbol\theta))}{\partial \boldsymbol\theta} = \frac{\partial \log(f_X({\bf X}; \boldsymbol\theta,\boldsymbol\Phi))}{\partial \boldsymbol\theta}
- 
\frac{\partial \log(f_T({\bf T}; \boldsymbol\theta,\boldsymbol\Phi))}{\partial \boldsymbol\theta}
$$

and so, we need to prove that

$$E_\boldsymbol\theta\left[\frac{\partial \log(f_X({\bf X}; \boldsymbol\theta,\boldsymbol\Phi))}{\partial \boldsymbol\theta} \mid {\bf T} \right]  =  \frac{\partial \log(f_T({\bf T}; \boldsymbol\theta,\boldsymbol\Phi))}{\partial \boldsymbol\theta}$$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, we note that

\begin{align}E_\boldsymbol\theta\left[\frac{\partial \log(f_X({\bf X}; \boldsymbol\theta,\boldsymbol\Phi))}{\partial \boldsymbol\theta} \mid {\bf T} \right] 
&= 
\frac{\partial \log(f_T({\bf T}; \boldsymbol\theta,\boldsymbol\Phi))}{\partial \boldsymbol\theta}
+
E_\boldsymbol\theta\left[\frac{\partial \log(f_{X | T}({\bf X} | {\bf T}; \boldsymbol\theta))}{\partial \boldsymbol\theta} \mid {\bf T} \right]
\end{align}

Under $\boldsymbol\theta$, we have

$$ E_\boldsymbol\theta\left[\frac{\partial \log(f_{X | T}({\bf X} | {\bf T}; \boldsymbol\theta))}{\partial \boldsymbol\theta} \mid {\bf T} \right] = {\bf 0} $$

by the properties of the likelihood.

Therefore,

\begin{align}E_\boldsymbol\theta\left[\frac{\partial \log(f_X({\bf X}; \boldsymbol\theta,\boldsymbol\Phi))}{\partial \boldsymbol\theta} \mid {\bf T} \right] 
&= 
\frac{\partial \log(f_T({\bf T}; \boldsymbol\theta,\boldsymbol\Phi))}{\partial \boldsymbol\theta}
\end{align}